# AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime notification not working on iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, ios11, avplayerviewcontroller

In previous versions there was Done button on AVPlayer and when the following notification was added, it worked :

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(CourseDetailViewController.moviePlayBackDidFinish(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
```

Now suddenly, in **iOS 11**, firstly there is no Done button (it is replaced by cross button), and secondly, on tapping cross button, `NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` is not getting fired.
This is how I am presenting the player with help of `AVPlayerViewController`

```
player = AVPlayer(url: url! as URL)
let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerViewController.player = player
self.present(playerViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions. This is regarded as especially tiresome in titles, so I have downvoted - you are an experienced Stack Overflow user and are expected to know this.

Comment: @halfer : I appreciate. As far as I know (I am really not interested in this but rather in the solution), when you draft a question, stack overflow itself restricts use of certain keywords in the question title. If they think URGENT is not to be used, I have no worries removing it (the matter which you yourself took in your hands :))
I have a certain reputation to edit questions, but i only do so when it is valid.
Anyways, now if you can address the more concerning part i.e. THE ANSWER.

Comment: (A discussion thread was deleted by participants here, to make room for on-topic discussion. I'll leave a piece of advice popular with the community, which is: downvotes are not personal, they are just messages.)

Comment: @CupawnTae : Yes. AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime is called if the player is closed, no matter if it is closed forcefully. This has always worked in previous iOS versions. My app which was live started giving issue when iOS 11 was updated.

Comment: I just tested this on iOS 9.3 and when I tapped "Done", `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` was *not* fired, so I think something else is going on here. Is there a chance somewhere else in your code is (was) programmatically posting `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` or calling your `moviePlayBackDidFinish` directly?

Comment: `object: nil`. You are observing all `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` notifications, not just for your player. You should be observing notifications for the specific AVPlayer instance you are interested in. Otherwise you are setting yourself up for some interesting bugs in the future.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the poster is playing media not with `AVPlayer`, but with `AVPlayerViewController`. Is that correct? `AVPlayer` could not be showing a "done" or "cross" button, but `AVPlayerViewController` could.

Comment: @quellish : Updated the question to show how I am presenting the player. I also passed player.currentItem in object instead of nil but the notification is not fired anyway.

Comment: @Nitish the fact remains that, as per the documentation and empirical evidence, this notification *shouldn't* be posted when "done" is tapped. Have you considered my questions?

Comment: from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification.name/1386566-avplayeritemdidplaytoendtime): _"This notification may be posted on a different thread than the one on which the observer was registered."_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification.name/1386566-avplayeritemdidplaytoendtime) states that `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` is

> Posted when the item has played to its end time

which makes sense given the notification's name.

Conversely, tapping the Done (or X) button of your `AVPlayerViewController` before the item has finished playing means it *won't* play to its end time, and the notification therefore won't be posted.

Testing this on iOS 9.3 shows the behaviour is the same as it is on iOS 11.

Something else must have changed in your application, or in iOS 11's interaction with your application, that is causing the change of behaviour you're observing. Without seeing your code anything else would be speculation, but from what you describe, `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` is behaving as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the test results. The thing is i haven't touched the code for many months and the issue started coming. The only difference is that in iOS 11, Done button is not there on the player and is replaced by cross button. And thus the notification is not getting called.

Comment: I understand, but my point is that the notification *shouldn't* be posted - so something else must be different. It could well be a change in behaviour in iOS 11, but I would be looking for something other than AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime for the root cause, e.g. the questions I posted in comments on the question above. Are you 100% sure the notification was being posted, rather than something else calling the same handler method? If so, was something in your own code posting the notification when "done" was tapped?

Comment: Pranjal Bikash Das in case you swing back here, I reverted your suggested edit because that's not a correct use of `code` formatting - the text "iOS 9.3" for example is not code and should not be marked as such

Comment: @CupawnTae: you can ping editors here, even if they have not also commented. Just get the person's username, remove any spaces, and prefix it with an `@` symbol, e.g. `@PranjalBikashDas` in this case. I believe you can get away with the first bit as well, e.g. `@Pranjal`.